# Armazenar cada noticia em uma tabela ou uma tabela para todas as noticias?

Tags: php, mysql

Estou criando um site de notícias. Para um banco de dados mais eficiente e rápido é mais correto que eu crie uma tabela para armazenar todas as noticias ou crie uma tabela para cada noticia?

No caso de criar uma tabela para cada noticia seria feito dinamicamente com php.

Comment: Acredito que uma tabela com varias noticias....

Answer (score 1):

O correto é criar uma tabela onde ficarão todas as notícias. Cada linha dessa tabela será uma notícia diferente e cada coluna representa uma propriedade da notícia (texto, data, autor, ou qualquer outra coisa que você precise guardar). Talvez vc precise de outras tabelas para guardar autores, fotos, etc... vai depender do que a sua aplicação precisa.

Sendo bem sincero, não faz o menor sentido armazenar uma notícia por tabela... Sem querer ofender, me parece que você precisa urgentemente revisar os conceitos de banco de dados...

Espero ter ajudado.